# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name' ( related to different tensorflow versions )

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, scipy

While running the jupyter notebook online in google colab, no error is coming out, 
but while running the code in offline mode, it's giving following error. :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-04f071b889cd> in <module>
      4     start_time = time.time()
      5     x, min_val, info = fmin_l_bfgs_b(evaluator.loss, x.flatten(),
----> 6                            fprime=evaluator.grads, maxfun=20)
      7     print(min_val)
      8     end_time = time.time()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py in fmin_l_bfgs_b(func, x0, fprime, args, approx_grad, bounds, m, factr, pgtol, epsilon, iprint, maxfun, maxiter, disp, callback, maxls)
    197 
    198     res = _minimize_lbfgsb(fun, x0, args=args, jac=jac, bounds=bounds,
--> 199                            **opts)
    200     d = {'grad': res['jac'],
    201          'task': res['message'],

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py in _minimize_lbfgsb(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds, disp, maxcor, ftol, gtol, eps, maxfun, maxiter, iprint, callback, maxls, **unknown_options)
    333             # until the completion of the current minimization iteration.
    334             # Overwrite f and g:
--> 335             f, g = func_and_grad(x)
    336         elif task_str.startswith(b'NEW_X'):
    337             # new iteration

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py in func_and_grad(x)
    283     else:
    284         def func_and_grad(x):
--> 285             f = fun(x, *args)
    286             g = jac(x, *args)
    287             return f, g

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py in function_wrapper(*wrapper_args)
    324     def function_wrapper(*wrapper_args):
    325         ncalls[0] += 1
--> 326         return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
    327 
    328     return ncalls, function_wrapper

<ipython-input-27-551cb8cb7b3f> in loss(self, x)
      6     def loss(self, x):
      7         assert self.loss_value is None
----> 8         loss_value, grad_values = eval_loss_and_grads(x)
      9         self.loss_value = loss_value
     10         self.grad_values = grad_values

<ipython-input-26-8de948cd1256> in eval_loss_and_grads(x)
      1 def eval_loss_and_grads(x):
      2     x = x.reshape((1, height, width, 3))
----> 3     outs = f_outputs([x])
      4     loss_value = outs[0]
      5     grad_values = outs[1].flatten().astype('float64')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   3287         feed_symbols != self._feed_symbols or self.fetches != self._fetches or
   3288         session != self._session):
-> 3289       self._make_callable(feed_arrays, feed_symbols, symbol_vals, session)
   3290 
   3291     fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py in _make_callable(self, feed_arrays, feed_symbols, symbol_vals, session)
   3213     # Handle fetches.
   3214     for x in self.outputs + self.fetches:
-> 3215       callable_opts.fetch.append(x.name)
   3216     # Handle updates.
   3217     callable_opts.target.append(self.updates_op.name)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

In offline mode, following versions of tensoflow and keras respectively : 1.14.0, 2.3.0

In google colab, following versions of tensoflow and keras respectively : 1.15.0, 2.2.5

[ Note : i checked the code, and when i ran it on colab, it was working. ]

The code is :

```
import time
for i in range(iterations):
    print('Start of iteration', i)
    start_time = time.time()
    x, min_val, info = fmin_l_bfgs_b(evaluator.loss, x.flatten(),
                           fprime=evaluator.grads, maxfun=20)
    print(min_val)
    end_time = time.time()
    print('Iteration %d completed in %ds' % (i, end_time - start_time))
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn't seem complete, you reference the variable x that isn't defined here, i.e "x.flatten()", what is that variable's value on the first iteration?

Comment: From the [https://keras.io/](Keras homepage) "Keras is compatible with: Python 2.7-3.6." whereas the traceback shows you are using 3.7. This may or may not be the cause of your problem

Comment: It's also Python 3.7 in the example with the error. Is it Python 3.7 in the version that works? Worth checking.

Comment: Is your issue resolved now? Else, can you share the code to reproduce your issue so that we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: @TensorflowWarriors sorry for late replies, as the issue got resolved when i again installed anaconda and tensorflow dependencies. The issue might be due to mistmatch in different versions of libraries and causing conflict between new and older versions of libraries :)

Comment: @TheKewlStore it was part of some medium tutorial on "Neural Style transfer", but later on i got issue resolved by using different measure :)

Comment: @MattL.i checked and some libraries were conflicting with 3.7 at that time i exactly don't remebered how the issues solved as i just reinstalled through anaconda environment

Answer (score 0):

Try to install packages again, as it solved my issue, like i reinstalled some conflicting packages again in anaconda environment